# One column missing horizontal lines

Tags: python-3.x, latex, tabular, pdflatex

I am working on a project which involves **automatic report generation using latex and python.** I  open a text file extract the content use some regex operation and store the desired value in an array. From this array, I am making a table in my report. Everything is fine and good. The only issue I am facing is **that horizontal lines are not being made in my first column after every row.** **THE FIRST COLUMN IS WITHOUT A HORIZONTAL LINE SEPARATOR FOR ROWS.**

This is my latex code for template.tex

% \begin{center}

% \begin{tabular}{|m{4cm}|m{2.5cm}|m{2.5cm}|m{2cm}|m{2cm}|}

% \hline

% \textbf{Meeting Name} & \textbf{Started At} & \textbf{Ended At} & \textbf{Duration (min)} & \textbf{Number of Participants} \\

% \hline

% \hline

% % for index, row in df.iterrows() %}

% {% if row['Meeting Name'] != '' %}

% {{ row['Meeting Name'] }} & {{ row['Started At'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }} & {{ row['Ended At'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }} & {{ row['Duration']//60 }} & {{ row['Number of Participants'] }} \\

% \cline{2-5}

% {% endif %}

% {% endfor %}

% \hline

% \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{\textbf{Total call duration (min)}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{{ total_duration }} \\

% \cline{1-3} \cline{4-5}

% \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{\textbf{Total participants}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{{ total_participants }} \\

% \hline

% \end{tabular}

% \end{center}

% \begin{center}

% \textbf{Total call duration: {{ total_duration }} min} \\

% \textbf{Total participants: {{ total_participants }}}

% \end{center}

% \end{document}

My python code from where data is pushed to this template
# LaTeX template

template = r'''

\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|m{4cm}|m{2.5cm}|m{2.5cm}|m{2.5cm}|m{2cm}|}

\hline

\textbf{Meeting Name} & \textbf{Started At} & \textbf{Ended At} & \textbf{Duration(min)} & \textbf{Number of Participants} \\

\hline

\hline

''' + table_data + r'''

\hline

\multicolumn{3}{|r|}{\textbf{Total call duration}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{''' + str(total_duration) + r'''} \\

\hline

\multicolumn{3}{|r|}{\textbf{Total participants}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{''' + str(total_participants) + r'''} \\

\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}

'''

Comment: Can you please edit your question an put your code in code blocks so we can see which of the empty lines are actually part of your code? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.